# Scala Slick foreignkey deferrable param

Tags: scala, slick

In class I am declaring fkey:

```
lazy val defaultStoreTypeIdFk = foreignKey("cl_default_store_type_fk", defaultStoreTypeId, StoreTypeDomain)(r => r.id, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.NoAction)
```

which with pure SQL I would create by:

```
ALTER TABLE public.client ADD CONSTRAINT cl_default_store_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (default_store_type_id) REFERENCES public.store_type(id) ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE;
```

In my app implementation, database for integration is created based on classes, so fkeys are created based on foreignKey methods. How can I create this fkey with DEFERRABLE to true ?
I dont see in this method DEFERRABLE param.. is it possible ?